# Ansible Playbook fails start Apache Cassandra

Tags: ansible, cassandra, systemd

I have been tried ran a Ansible Playboo, but after change the `cassandra.yml` when the service tries start I received this error bellow:

```
● cassandra.service - LSB: distributed storage system for structured data
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/cassandra; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since sex 2021-04-02 01:06:05 UTC; 15min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 5052 ExecStop=/etc/rc.d/init.d/cassandra stop (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 4883 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/cassandra start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4972 (code=exited, status=3)

abr 02 01:05:37 ip-10-5-10-195.ec2.internal cassandra[4883]: Starting Cassandra: OK
abr 02 01:05:37 ip-10-5-10-195.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Started LSB: distributed storage system for structured data.
abr 02 01:05:40 ip-10-5-10-195.ec2.internal systemd[1]: cassandra.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=3/NOTIMPLEMENTED
abr 02 01:05:40 ip-10-5-10-195.ec2.internal runuser[5063]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user cassandra by (uid=0)
abr 02 01:05:40 ip-10-5-10-195.ec2.internal cassandra[5052]: Shutdown Cassandra: kill: sending signal to 4972 failed: No such process
abr 02 01:05:40 ip-10-5-10-195.ec2.internal runuser[5063]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session closed for user cassandra
abr 02 01:06:05 ip-10-5-10-195.ec2.internal cassandra[5052]: ERROR: could not stop cassandra
abr 02 01:06:05 ip-10-5-10-195.ec2.internal systemd[1]: cassandra.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
abr 02 01:06:05 ip-10-5-10-195.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Unit cassandra.service entered failed state.
abr 02 01:06:05 ip-10-5-10-195.ec2.internal systemd[1]: cassandra.service failed.
```

In my *cassandra.yml* I just change the mount point/path where Cassandra stores the **data** and sure that this works.

Looking at Cassandra `system.log` I found:

```
ERROR [main] 2021-04-05 16:57:34,074 CassandraDaemon.java:822 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:240)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:676)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:800)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to mkdirs /hints; unable to start server
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.createAllDirectories(DatabaseDescriptor.java:1395)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.<init>(CommitLog.java:95)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.construct(CommitLog.java:78)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.<clinit>(CommitLog.java:65)
    ... 3 common frames omitted
```

It's weird because I create the directory at new mount point with `cassandra:cassandra` permitions:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 cassandra cassandra   6 abr  5 14:46 commitlog
drwxr-xr-x  2 cassandra cassandra   6 abr  5 14:46 data
drwxr-xr-x  2 cassandra cassandra   6 abr  5 16:53 hints
drwxr-xr-x  2 cassandra cassandra   6 abr  5 16:53 saved_caches
```

I have been spend long hours trying solve but without success, someone my can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my fault.
It's necessary define a `cassandra.service` to Systemd manages Cassandra:

*path*: `/etc/systemd/system/cassandra.service`

And adjust like you installation

```
[Unit]
Description=Cassandra Cluster Node Daemon

[Service]
Type=forking
User=cassandra
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/echo "Starting Cassandra Daemon"
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/cassandra
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/echo "Cassandra Daemon Running"

ExecStopPost=/usr/bin/rm -rf /cassandra/saved_caches;/usr/bin/echo "Cassandra Daemon Stopped"

SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```